# HTML element in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using JQuery autocomplete option to get values from database using PHP. I have 2 text boxes and I am trying to use same PHP file to get the required results.
My HTML code is

```
<tr>
 <td>LOB</td>
  <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ABC" class="autocomplete"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Project Name</td>
 <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="PQR" class="autocomplete"/></td>
</tr>
```

and my JQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: 'LiveSearch.php?name='+ $(".autocomplete").attr('name') + '&',
minLength: 2
});
});
```

But as these there are 2 elements with same class. I am not getting correct `arrr('name')`. `MySQL` will differ based on this name. I tried (this) but still not getting the result.
If I am in the first text box then name should be of that text box etc..
Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: u want value from txtbox1 ,or txtbox2?

Answer (score 1):

You can target the textbox using name.

```
$('[name=ABC]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use id to differentiate

```
<tr>
 <td>LOB</td>
  <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="ABC" id="id1" class="autocomplete"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Project Name</td>
 <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="PQR" id="id2" class="autocomplete"/></td>
</tr>
```

//Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: 'LiveSearch.php?name='+ $("#id1").attr('name') + '&',
minLength: 2
});
});
```

Comment: Hi Pratik, I am using same LiveSearch.php where I have defined a logic to read attribute name and fetch the respective data. each(function) is working. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the scope of 'all autocompletes' and 'the current automplete'.  One way of dealing with this is to use jQuery's each() method:

```
$('.various-things').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('something');
});
```

This would log the 'something' attribute of **each** .various-things on the page.  It looks like what you'd need is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".autocomplete" ).each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: 'LiveSearch.php?name='+ $(this).attr('name') + '&',
      minLength: 2
    });
  });
});
```

Now it'll find all autocompletes and set them up using their own name.